# how get dynamic div width in javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, resizable, jquery-ui-resizable

I have two div demo1 and demo2 .I need if I drag demo1 left to right and right to left in that time demo2 width automatically adjust .
I tried this

```
<div class="wrapper">
              <div class="demo"></div>
              <div class="demo2"></div>
</div> 
<STYLE>
.demo {
    float: left; 
    width: 50%;
    height:100%;
    background-color: red;
}
.demo2 { 
    float: left;
    background-color: black;
    width: 50%;
    height:100%;
}</STYLE>
<script type="text/javascript">
         (function(){

      maxWidth=$('.wrapper').width();
      $('.demo').resizable(function(e){

        var x = e.pageX;
        alert(x);

        $(this).width(x);
        $('.demo2').width(maxWidth-x);


    });
})()
 </script>
```

But when I drag demo1 left to right, demo2's width is not adjusting automatically .
Please any one tell me what is wrong in my code.

Comment: you are missing a `</div>` in your html to begin with

Comment: @k-nut that's my copy mistake Please if you any thing about problem please help me

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle out of this?

Comment: @k-nut i tried but it's not work in jsfiddle

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: @k-nut same code copy into jsfiddle but it's  not worked  i am new to JavaScript and jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the syntax. You can bind to the `resize` event to do what you want:

```
(function () {
    var maxWidth = $('.wrapper').width();
    $('.demo').resizable({
        resize: function (e, ui) {
            var x = e.pageX;
            $(this).width(x);
            $('.demo2').width(maxWidth - x);;
        }
    });
})();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rcsxj3xb/1/

Comment: thanks for reply i tried as you side using resize but not working

Comment: i need  when  i drag red div left to right black div automatically screen  adjuest ex: red div(50%) black div (50%) when i drag red div 70% black dive adjust to 30% Please give me any idea

Comment: But this is exactly what is happening in the link I posted. You can drag the line between the red and the black div in the middle to resize the red element. It works perfectly fine in FF and Chrome for me.

Comment: what do you see in the fiddle and what happens when you drag? also what browser are you using?

Comment: in jsfiddle when i red div darg left to right black div not adjust to screen automatically so Please help me

Comment: So you want the wrapper to take the full screen width?! http://jsfiddle.net/rcsxj3xb/2/

Comment: thanks but only one problem is when i placed .wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}
but i need height also 100% so when i placed height :100% in that time out put not working

Comment: In that case you also need to set `height:100%` for `html` and `body` http://jsfiddle.net/rcsxj3xb/5/

Comment: Yes i tried already as you said it's not working in google-chrome browser .wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
} in this case when i drag red div left to right black div comes under red div

Comment: Are you sure? I cannot reproduce what you said with chrome. I added some text so that you can clearly see that the div is indeed resized http://jsfiddle.net/rcsxj3xb/6/